# How can I sort xml atribute using simpleXML in php?

Tags: php, xml

I need to sort one of xml atributes, but I dont know how. I tried function `sort` but it was saying it has to be string. I need to sort tariffSpaceName, because one name can have severall numbers and I would like to have them together. Ill show only one of the subscribers, cause its really big xml file.

```
<?php
if (file_exists('2023-04-23-3622216414-5_13324_10_00_100005-s.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('2023-04-23-3622216414-5_13324_10_00_100005-s.xml');

?>
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>tariffSpaceName</th>
            <th>serviceNumber</th>
            <th>coreProductNumber</th>
        </tr>


<?php
$count = count($xml->subscribers->subscriber);
for($aa=0; $aa<$count; $aa++) {

  foreach($xml->subscribers->subscriber[$aa]->attributes() as $key => $val) {
    if($key == "tariffSpaceName"){
sort($key);
      echo "<tr><td>[1]" . $val . "</td>";
    }

    if($key == "serviceNumber"){
      echo "<td>[2]" . $val . "</td>";
    }

    if($key == "summaryPriceWithTax"){
        echo "<td>[3]" . $val . "</td></tr>";
    }
  }

}
 echo "------<br>";
}else {
    exit('Failed to open test.xml.');
}

?>
</table>
</html>
```

```
<subscribers>
        <subscriber accountType="CUST" ownerRefNum="3622216414" ownerCustCode="" phoneNumber="601177068" customerAccountNumber="3622216414" tariffSpaceNumber="5900349478" tariffSpaceName="Böhmová Zdeňka" coreProductNumber="601177068" serviceNumber="601177068" parentServiceNumber="3622216414" serviceStatus="A" summaryPrice="8" summaryPriceTax="1.68" summaryPriceWithTax="9.68" mainTariff="Profil 2" serviceCategory="mobileVoice" noOfEdr="26">
```

Comment: You can not sort data _while_ you are looping over it, you need to sort it before. _"I tried function sort but it was saying it has to be string"_ - no, it must have said the exact opposite of that. `sort($key);` - your $key _is_ a string here, but `sort` can only sort arrays.

Comment: @CBroe I can put it above IFs and it will pop up this:          Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: sort(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Praxe\convertor.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Praxe\convertor.php(20): sort('accountType') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Praxe\convertor.php on line 20

Comment: Yes, and? Anything surprising about that? Just because you put `sort($key);` one(?) line higher now, doesn't change anything about what `$key` contains.

Comment: thats why Iam asking :) Iam not expirienced and this is my first time working with it. I didnt asked just to get flamed.

Comment: _"I need to sort one of xml atributes"_ does not make much sense to begin with. I am guessing, what you actually want to sort here, are those subscribers - and you want to sort them _by_ that `tariffSpaceName` value. So you need to put your your subscribers into an array first of all, and then you can sort that array.

Comment: thats exactly what Iam trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML with SimpleXML will return the document element. With the example you provided this would be the `subscribers` element.

You can use `iterator_to_array()` (while ignoring the keys) to convert the `Traversable` into an array and then use array function to sort/map the data.

SimpleXML allows to address attributes by name using array syntax. Here is no need to iterate them.

```php
$subscribersElement = new SimpleXMLElement(getXMLString());
// convert traversable into an array (ignoring keys)
$subscribers = iterator_to_array($subscribersElement->subscriber, false);

// sort using custom compare
usort(
    $subscribers,
    function(SimpleXMLElement $a, SimpleXMLElement $b) {
        return strnatcasecmp ($a['tariffSpaceName'], $b['tariffSpaceName']);
    }
);

// map and dump
var_dump(
    array_map(
        function(SimpleXMLElement $subscriber) {
          return [
           'tariffSpaceName' => (string)$subscriber['tariffSpaceName'],
           'serviceNumber' => (string)$subscriber['serviceNumber'],
           'summaryPriceWithTax' => (string)$subscriber['summaryPriceWithTax']
          ];
        },
        $subscribers
    )
);


function getXMLString() {
    return <<<'XML'
<subscribers>
    <subscriber accountType="CUST" ownerRefNum="3622216414" ownerCustCode="" phoneNumber="601177068" customerAccountNumber="3622216414" tariffSpaceNumber="5900349479" tariffSpaceName="Böhmová Zdeňka 2" coreProductNumber="601177068" serviceNumber="601177068" parentServiceNumber="3622216414" serviceStatus="A" summaryPrice="8" summaryPriceTax="1.68" summaryPriceWithTax="8.68" mainTariff="Profil 2" serviceCategory="mobileVoice" noOfEdr="26"/>
    <subscriber accountType="CUST" ownerRefNum="3622216414" ownerCustCode="" phoneNumber="601177068" customerAccountNumber="3622216414" tariffSpaceNumber="5900349478" tariffSpaceName="Böhmová Zdeňka" coreProductNumber="601177068" serviceNumber="601177068" parentServiceNumber="3622216414" serviceStatus="A" summaryPrice="8" summaryPriceTax="1.68" summaryPriceWithTax="9.68" mainTariff="Profil 2" serviceCategory="mobileVoice" noOfEdr="26"/>
</subscribers>
XML;
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tariffSpaceName"]=>
    string(17) "Böhmová Zdeňka"
    ["serviceNumber"]=>
    string(9) "601177068"
    ["summaryPriceWithTax"]=>
    string(4) "9.68"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["tariffSpaceName"]=>
    string(19) "Böhmová Zdeňka 2"
    ["serviceNumber"]=>
    string(9) "601177068"
    ["summaryPriceWithTax"]=>
    string(4) "8.68"
  }
}
```